# ImageMagick: custom rank filter? Like erode or dilate or median but a different rank, e.g. a 'percentile' filter?

Tags: filter, imagemagick, pixel, rank, median

When applying a rank filter with ImageMagick such as erode or delate or median, it takes the minimum (`erode`) or maximum (`dilate`) or middle (`median`) value of all pixels within a certain radius or custom shape around each source pixel.

Is it also possible to take a *custom rank* of the surrounding pixel values? For example when using a 5x5 square, with the `erode` or `dilate` or `median` filters, respectively the lowest, highest, of middle value of the 25 pixels surrounding each pixel is taken. What I'm looking for is a way to take the 8th or 23rd value, for example.

Perhaps this could be expressed as a percentile, e.g. take the 20% percentile value of an arbitrary area surrounding each pixel. Which in case of a 7x7 square would be the 0.2*7*7 = the 9th value out of the total 49 in order.

The `erode`, `dilate` and `median` filters would correspond to the 0%, 100%, and 50% percentiles, respectively.

Comment: I updated my answer if you'd care to have another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do that easily in **ImageMagick** - other than compiling in your own *"process module"*. The best introduction to that is by `snibgo` and actually for Windows - see the `sortpixels.c` example [here](http://im.snibgo.com/customim.htm#sortpixels.c)

---

One tool that can do this simply from the command-line is [libvips](https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/8.5/libvips-morphology.html#vips-rank) with its `im_rank()` function.

So, if you want index 8 from a sorted list of 5x5 neighbours, you could do:

```
vips im_rank input.png result.png 5 5 8
```

I did a quick test by generating a random image with **ImageMagick** and choosing successively greater values for `index` and the output images got successively brighter - but that was the sum-total of my testing. I have no reason to believe it will not work - it is an excellent library and very fast and frugal.

---

If you can live with Python, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
from scipy import stats

# Modal filter
def modal(P):
    """
    We receive P[0]..P[8] with the pixels in the 3x3 surrounding window
    Sort neighbours and take N'th in list
    """
    N = 3
    P.sort()
    return P[N]

# Open image and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
im = np.array(im)

# Run modal filter, change filter size here
result = generic_filter(im, modal, (3, 3))

# Save result
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

You can change the filter size/shape to, say 5x5 by changing this line:

```
result = generic_filter(im, modal, (5, 5))
```

And as it is, it will take the third smallest neighbour, as counting starts from 0. So, use `N=0` if you want the minimum in the 3x3 neighbourhood, or `N=8` if you want the maximum in a 3x3 neighbourhood.

---

Another option might be to use [CImg](http://cimg.eu) which is a simple-to-use, header-only C++ library (no DLLs/libXXX.a/libXXX.so files) that can actually read and write PGM files natively without needing anything external. So you could run an **ImageMagick** command and cause it to write a PGM file on `stdout` and read that in using **CImg**, process it and write it out filtered again. That would probably be easier than writing an **ImageMagick** *"process module"* and you wouldn't need to build **ImageMagick** from source anew for every release.

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, vips, libvips, filter, rank, ranking, median, dilate, erode, window, 3x3, 5x5, NxN, percentile, Python, PIL, Pillow, image, image processing.