# Is there any way to only extract "corner" vertex points from a PNG?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, png

I'm currently experimenting with the idea of extracting data points from a specific PNG file. For reference, the PNG file looks like this :
[Picture of PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo00R.png)

The current code I'm using to extract the data looks like this, I'm using the Python image library to identify points of the image :

```
def imageProcess(filename) :
    #Declaring data object
    data = []
    #Loading image for modification
    with Image.open(filename) as im:
        px = im.load()
        #Grabbing values
        width,height = im.size
        print(width , height)

        #For loop
        for x in range(width) :
            for y in range(height) :
                #Removes white space from the image
                if px[x,y] != (255,255,255,0) :
                    data.append({"x" : x*5, "y" : y*5,"color" :  px [ x , y ]})

        print(type(data))

        return data
```

Whilst this code does work fine, I'm trying to discard the data points that represent a line in the PNG file, I only want the corners to be specific. To give a better idea of what I want :

Instead of :

```
{'x': 518, 'y': 741, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
# All of the data below is a waste, I don't need it
{'x': 518, 'y': 742, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 743, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 744, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 745, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 746, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 747, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 748, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 749, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 750, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 751, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 752, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 753, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 754, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 755, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 756, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 757, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 758, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 759, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 760, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 761, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 762, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 763, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 764, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 765, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 766, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
# The point below represents the corner
{'x': 518, 'y': 767, 'color': (244, 244, 244, 2)}
```

I only want the first and last value since it represents the corners :

```
#This is what I want to achieve
{'x': 518, 'y': 741, 'color': (226, 226, 226, 17)}
{'x': 518, 'y': 767, 'color': (244, 244, 244, 2)}
```

I'm welcome to using different python libraries apart from PIL if needed to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Edit : Here is a (sorry for the low res) [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpdz.png) explaining what data points I need to get and all of the data points need to be discarded. I've put red dots identifying what points I need to get. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could add a second marked-up image identifying in red, or with circles, which points you are trying to find?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm trying to identify the corners, like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpdz.png. I apologise for the low res. I only need the start and endpoints of a line in this PNG image. Thank you.

Comment: Is your actual image that poor (low-res)? Can you see that many of the corner points you are looking for are actually not present - there are gaps in the image at this points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have the time to write up a proper Python answer like I normally would, but it seems cruel not to show you how you might do it. I used *"Hit and Miss Morphology"* which you can find in **OpenCV**, **scikt-image** and **wand**. I used **ImageMagick** in the Terminal to generate this:

[image]

Here is the command and it would be pretty similar in **wand** since that is a Python **ImageMagick** binding:

```
magick plan.png -alpha off -threshold 99%  \
    \( +clone -define morphology:showkernel=1 -morphology HMT "3x3>: nan,0,0 0,nan,nan 0,nan,nan " -morphology Dilate Ring -background red -alpha shape  \) -composite result.png
```

The crucial part in there is the *"Hit and Miss"* kernel, which is here:

```
"3x3>: nan,0,0 0,nan,nan 0,nan,nan "
```

That means I am looking for this 3x3 shape:

```
ANY    BLACK  BLACK
BLACK  ANY    ANY
BLACK  ANY    ANY
```

Hopefully you can see that is a horizontal and a vertical black line meeting in the top-left corner of the 3x3 shape where the actual corner is not necessarily black because those bits are missing in your diagram! You would use a `1` if you wanted to insist on a white pixel at some location in the 3x3 grid. You would use a larger grid if you waned to be even. ore sure you were dealing with a corner of a longer line.

The `>` means that I want to find that corner at any of the 4 positions you would get if you rotated it 90, 180 and 270 degrees, so I am looking for top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left corners.

You can see as much if I print the debug output corners showing the kernels:

```
Kernel #0 "User Defined" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from 0 to 0
Forming a output range from 0 to 0 (Zero-Summing)
 0:       nan         0         0
 1:         0       nan       nan
 2:         0       nan       nan
Kernel #1 "User Defined@90" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from 0 to 0
Forming a output range from 0 to 0 (Zero-Summing)
 0:         0         0       nan
 1:       nan       nan         0
 2:       nan       nan         0
Kernel #2 "User Defined@180" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from 0 to 0
Forming a output range from 0 to 0 (Zero-Summing)
 0:       nan       nan         0
 1:       nan       nan         0
 2:         0         0       nan
Kernel #3 "User Defined@270" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from 0 to 0
Forming a output range from 0 to 0 (Zero-Summing)
 0:         0       nan       nan
 1:         0       nan       nan
 2:       nan         0         0
```

Note that the `-morphology Dilate Ring -background red -alpha shape` is just for drawing the red circles around the points so you can see them. You can omit this and you will just get the points on a blank canvas.

If this method interests you, there is an excellent description by Anthony Thyssen [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#hitmiss), but start at the top of the page if you are new to morphology.

Comment: Good answer! You can also find angles using cross-correlation (convolution) with the L-shaped kernel and its rotations.

Comment: @AlexAlex Indeed. It would also be very simple to adapt the filter in this answer to look for P[1], P[2], P[3] and P[6] being zero.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55558489/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access the first and last elements in the returned `data` list. You can do that like so:

```
[data[0]] + [data[-1]]
```

**How does this work?**

```
data[0]
```

retrieves the first element in the data list, and

```
data[-1]
```

retrieves the last element in the data list.
Wrapping both in `[]` creates two single-element lists, which we then concatenate together using the `+` operator!